# How to run solrCloud with group of machine?

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I have installed *zookeeper* on 3 machines. And set zoo.conf file. It's running with configuration. I installed solr also on these 3 machine.

Now i need to know how to run solr cloud on group of machine with number of shards? 
My zookeeper configuration on  all machine :-

```
tickTime=2000
dataDir=/var/zookeeper
clientPort=2181
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2
server.1=instance-1:2888:3888
server.2=instance-2:2889:3889
server.3=instance-3:2890:3890
```

zookeeper command to run it on all machine:-

```
bin/zkServer.sh start conf/zoo.cfg
```

Solr command to run it:-

```
bin/solr start -e cloud -z instance-1:2181,instance-2:2182,instance-3:2183 -noprompt
```

It's just creating 2 shards on each machine individually on default port. Not able to  connect machine with each other.

Comment: Cloud use will explicitly visible when we enable replication. While creating collection a for your case set shards = 2 and replication as 2 and then you can see SolrCloud wisely distributing over the 3 SOLR nodes.